# Is there JSaveChooser available in java

Tags: java

Is there any type of JSaveChooser in java like JFileChooser? Basically I want to show a dialog like JFileChooser when user click "SAVE FILE" button in my java application, for getting path from user to saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

showSaveDialog() method  will work for you

```
JFrame parentFrame = new JFrame();
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Specify a file to save");   

int userSelection = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(parentFrame);

if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File fileToSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    System.out.println("Save as file: " + fileToSave.getAbsolutePath());
}
```